# Тире или запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении?

Tags: запятые, тире

Примеры из параграфа "**ТИРЕ В СЛОЖНОПОДЧИНЕННОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ**":

1) Если не уверен в себе, если не хватает мужества — откажись.

2) Что она натура честная — это мне ясно.

3) Художественность состоит в том, чтобы каждое слово было не только у места — чтобы оно было необходимо, неизбежно и чтобы как можно было меньше слов.

Из параграфа "**ЗАПЯТАЯ И ТИРЕ В СЛОЖНОПОДЧИНЕННОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ**":

1) Кто виноват из них, кто прав, — судить не нам.

2) Единственное, что мне здесь нравится, — это старый тенистый парк.

3) Он замолчал, но не потому, что ему не хватало слов, — ему не хватало дыхания.

Примеры, взятые из разных параграфов, отличаются пунктуацией при одинаковых условиях: первые примеры (отмеченные цифрой 1) объединяются наличием ряда однородных придаточных частей; примеры, отмеченные цифрами 2, имеют наличие слова "это"; в 3-их примерах опущены противительные союзы.

По какому принципу отдается предпочтение одному из знаков при одинаковых условиях? Или же разница состоит лишь в продолжительности паузы: при тире она короче, чем при запятой и тире?

Comment: Пропустил один пример - добавлено в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Условия далеко не одинаковы, но похожи.

*Кто виноват из них, кто прав, — (об этом) судить не нам.* || Слово "это" подразумевается по смыслу — связь с первой частью + однородные придаточные.

*Если не уверен в себе, если не хватает мужества — откажись.* || Здесь слово "это" никаким боком — нет ссылки на первую часть.

*Единственное (, что мне здесь нравится,) — это старый тенистый парк.* || Придаточное отделяется запятой и тире.

*Он замолчал, но не потому (, что ему не хватало слов,) — ему не хватало дыхания.* || То же самое, но при сопоставлении.

*Что она натура честная — это мне ясно.* || Придаточное не открывалось запятой.

Но:
*То, что она натура честная, — (это) мне ясно.*

*Художественность состоит в том, чтобы каждое слово было не только у места — (а) чтобы оно было необходимо, неизбежно и чтобы как можно было меньше слов.* || Просто интонационное тире перед однородным придаточным, которое можно заменить на запятую и союз "а".

Такой же простой пример:
*Сергей просил, чтобы она купила не только молоко — чтобы ещё купила сметану.

Сергей просил, чтобы она купила не только молоко, а чтобы ещё купила сметану.*

Comment: Спасбо за ответ, но все же одно правило остается мне непонятным. "Он замолчал, но не потому, что ему не хватало слов, — ему не хватало дыхания". Почему в этом предложении ставится запятая и тире, ведь в этом предложении, как и в  "Художественность состоит в том, чтобы каждое слово было не только у места — (а) чтобы оно было необходимо, неизбежно и чтобы как можно было меньше слов", упущены сопоставительный либо противительный союзы. Правило гласит, что тире ставится при отсутствии противительного союза или второй части сопоставительного союза между соподчиненными придаточными частями.

Comment: А здесь всё хитро (№3 - самое сложное). Дело в отрицании: замолчал **не потому** - по-другому. Это сопоставление (своего рода "нет - да"), при котором ставится запятая и тире. Тогда части вокруг тире **не однородны**: перед тире придаточное, после - **уже нет** (*ему не хватало дыхания* - не придаточное, а по правилу нужно). Да и **союз "а" не подходит** перед "ему не хватало". Но с "художественностью" дела обстоят совсем иначе. Структурно **части однородны**: *чтобы каждое слово было, чтобы оно было необходимо* - просто перечисление. Здесь нет прямого сопоставления, а тире - интонационное.

Comment: Вывод. *Он замолчал, но не потому, что ему не хватало слов, — ему не хватало дыхания.* - тире **не** между соподчинёнными придаточными; союз не пропущен, а вообще не подходит по смыслу; есть сопоставление. В другом предложении всё наоборот.